# strip_tags is keeping <a> but stripping its attributes

Tags: php, formatting, string-formatting, strip-tags

As the title says, when I use `strip_tags($text, "<a>...<others>")` and I insert hyperlinks into `$text`, I am left with an output of `<a>` rather than `<a href='...'>`.  How can I get around this, or is `strip_tags` not flexible enough for this?

Thanks!

```
$text = ucfirst($text);
$text = preg_replace('/\v+|\\\r\\\n/', '<br />', $text);
$allow = '<p><br><ul><ol><li><strong><img><em><a>';
$text = strip_tags($text, $allow);

// now, remove any suspect tags, etc.
preg_match_all("/<([^>]+)>/i", $allow, $allTags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

The input `$text` is:

```
<p>Lorum ipsum &nbsp;<a href="http://www.test.com">This is a test link</a>.</p>
```

Comment: According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), there is an example with `<a>` tags and attributes within those `<a>` tags being removed. Can you post the exact string you're using?

Comment: Please post your code and the desired result vs the actual result.

Comment: Code posted above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) removes all html elements or any thing that enclosed with `<>`.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

Example:

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
```

Output:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work exactly like you want.

```
$text = '<a href="http://www.someplace.com">link</a> <others>stuff</others>';
echo strip_tags($text,"<a>");
```

I'm left with the full `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="http://www.someplace.com">link</a> stuff
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/j1uE1

**Update**: With the code that you posted in your updated question, I ran it here and it still is providing the full `<a>` tag output. The attributes are not being stripped out.

http://3v4l.org/tFQ4l